# How to render external form in Activiti human task?

Tags: forms, external, activiti

I want to render some external form at some url on execution of "Activiti BPM tool" human task.

How can it be done with or without code.That is,How can i assign that human task an external form with some parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the form key.
You can assign a form key to any human task, the form key has no meaning to the engine, it is simply an id you can use to identify a form.

In the simplest case, the form key can be an external URL.

Once you have the form key associated with the task, then on execution, you can retrieve it using Java code or the Rest API and then generate the necessary form.

Comment: Where to write script against a human task?I couldn't find any script property against a human task in Activiti.
And if i simply assign a url to form key then it ll not be opened automatically on execution of that task?If can't then can you please share a sample code to open that url?

Comment: Correct, as I said, the form key doesnt actually "do": anything. It's just a correlation ID. You will need to code your own handler on the client side to use the form key.

Comment: Thanks.But i'm asking that where would i write that piece of code?
And can you share a sample code fore that purpose?

Comment: I wrote an integration that uses the Alpaca EForms engine and form keys a couple of years ago, You can find the github repo here: https://github.com/gdharley/activiti-alpaca

Be aware, it was built using Activiti 5.14 and there have been some Rest API changes in Activiti since then, meaning, the code will not work in 5.19 without some changes to the Rest calls. However, it should give you an idea of how to do what you want.